# Norm subscript notation in optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, notation

I'm reading a paper with the expression $H_k = \underset{H}{arg \hspace{3pt}min } \hspace{6pt} ||H-H_{k-1}||_{F,W}^2 \hspace{10pt} s.t. \hspace{5pt} H=H^T, Hy_k = s_k$

I've read that the subscript means that $F$ and $W$ are positive definite, and that makes sense for W since the article later goes on to state that $||X||_{F,W}^2 = ||XW||_F^2$ but $F$ is never mentioned again anywhere in the paper except in the subscript of the norm, so why is it there and what does it mean?
It's clear from the paper that the norm is the L2 norm, so the $F$ can't mean which norm it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your hint that there seems to be a relation with the L2 norm, I guess that $\lVert \cdot \rVert_F$ indicates that the [Frobenius Norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html) is used. That would also make sense as we need a matrix norm. My only concern is the notation $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{F,W}$ which I have not seen before. But as stated in your question, there seems to be an explanation for that in the paper.

Comment: Tank you, that makes a lot of sense. Do you have any tip on where to find answers to notation questions like this in the future other than "Simply have it all in your head", cause papers rarely explain their notation :/

Comment: Well, it depends on the paper. At least for more general stuff (like [matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) in this case) I would give Wikipedia a try, which often gives a good starting point. For notations that are more specific (maybe only used in a certain field) the referenced literature is often helpful. And of course Stack Exchange will also lead to an answer in most cases.